# Button not refreshing data

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I made an app that is supposed to get data from a website and display it in a label when the user click a button.

My issues are :

1. when I click the button for the first time, it gets the data and shows it
2. but if I click the button again it displays the same data instead of a refreshed data.

Here's a snippet of what I did:

```
import UIKit
import Osmosis

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var quote: UILabel! // My label supposed to display data

    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButtonContent: UIButton! // My button

    var array: [[String: AnyObject]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.quote.text = "No Data yet" // Initate my label

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /* The following function gets the data contain in a div on a website 
     and displays the data in the label
    */

    func getQuotes() {

        var updateText: String = ""

        Osmosis(errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.quote.text = "Error 500."
            }
            print(error)
        })
            .get(NSURL(string: "http://www.exemple.com")!)
            .find(OsmosisSelector(selector: ".wrapper"), type: .CSS)
            .populate([
                OsmosisPopulateKey.Single("div") : OsmosisSelector(selector: ".div")
                ], type: .CSS)
            .list { (dict) -> Void in
                self.array.append(dict)

                // Cast self.array[0] to String
                updateText = self.array[0]["div"] as! String



           // Truncate the string to remove unwanted /n /t
            updateText.removeAtIndex(updateText.startIndex)
            updateText.removeAtIndex(updateText.startIndex)
            updateText.removeAtIndex(updateText.endIndex.predecessor())

                print(updateText)
                //Update UI by the main thread (to avoid slow display update)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.quote.text = updateText
                }
            }
            .start()
    }

    // Actions made when the button is pressed

    @IBAction func refreshButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        getQuotes()
        refreshButtonContent.setTitle("Refresh Data", forState: .Normal)
    }

}
```

What is the mistake i did and how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? your last line of code does the behavior you've described, the button will always show the same text.

Comment: Did it call to `self.quote.text = updateText` on 2nd press?. Try print the updatedText and the received data out to see if they same or not

Comment: @Tj3n Apparently, the data differs from the `updatedText` on 2nd press and after. I don't understand why since I call `getQuotes` (which contains `self.quote.text = updatedText`) every time I press the button. So I suppose that every time I press the button, the updatedText should be set to the data.

Comment: I think i know why, its ur `self.array[0]["div"]`, mean u always use ur object at index 0 in the array, which is ALWAYS ur first `getQuotes` received data, u should call `self.array.last["div"]` or extract the object as `[String: AnyObject]` then get the the value with `["div"]` key to get the newest object, not the same one

Comment: @Tj3n I tried to set `updateText = self.array.last["div"]`but I get the following error: `ViewController.swift:52:41: Value of optional type '[String : AnyObject]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending `dict` to `self.array` but then you're always accessing the first element in `self.array`. Here: `updateText = self.array[0]["div"] as! String`

So its "always" going to work on the first run (assuming something exists at index 0) but it will not "work" on subsequent runs because the index is not keeping up with the button press. You should either replace the contents of `self.array` or just not use an array or use an index that is up to date with the number of times you've pressed the button.

Do you need the array somewhere else in the code? Why not just do `self.quote.text = dict["div"] as! String`

Comment: I set `updatedText = self.array[0]["div"] as! String` because I need to be able to truncate the string. I updated my code in order to let you see why I use `updatedText`

Comment: @Mehdi You're still accessing the same array element every single time.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now I understand my mistake. Is there a way to always access the last element of my array ?

Comment: @Mehdi Sure, `self.array.lastObject` be sure to accept the answer if this worked.

Comment: `self.array.lastObject` didn't worked but `self.array.last` let me access the last object. The thing is that I can't access a particular element in it like I did with `self.array[0]["div"]`. How can I do that ?

Comment: @Mehdi What does your array consist of? If its an array of dictionaries then you should just be able to do `self.array.last["div"]`, if its an array of something else than that is another problem entirely.

Comment: My arrays does contain dictionaries, as you can see in `.list {}`. If I try to set `updateText = self.array.last["div"]` I get the following error: `Value of optional type '[String : AnyObject]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?. And if I set `updateText = self.array.last!["div"]` it returns `nil`

Comment: I figured out why it didn't worked. Using `self.array.last!["quotes"]` works fine !